# Copy images/videos from the assets ref. URL to the App Folder

Tags: image, video, copy, uiimagepickercontroller, assets

I'm using a UIimagePicker to allow the user to import images and videos to the app. I'm loading the entire image/video in memory to be able to write them in the app folder. Is there a way to copy the image/video from the assets url provided by the "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" to the application folder directly without loading the file in memory?

The delegate of the uiimagepicker that I'm using is:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:       (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

I'm new to iOS, please excuse me if i'm missing some trivial way to do it.
Thanks,